# Getting error "creation of HelloWorld errored: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

Pretty new to Solidity and just tried the first HelloWorld smart contract in Remix IDE and stumbled upon this error, while trying to deploy the smart contract.

```
creation of HelloWorld pending...
creation of HelloWorld errored: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

My code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract HelloWorld {
    string public greet = "Hello World!";
}
```

The Compiler version is set to `0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce`

Not sure what I am missing, hence any all help and guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: I copy pasted your code in solidity remix online IDE. It compiled with no error as it should. There is nothing wrong in the code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the problem is with your browser. Reload remix and paste the code back in. No issue with the code itself.