# Solidity Error Message on Deployment: "Cannot Convert Undefined or Null to Object"

Tags: solidity

I'm following an udemy course and have encounters an error in my code:

**creation of Lottery errored: Cannot convert undefined or null to object**

To test if it is an error on my end, I used the provided source code from the instructor, however the same issue is showing up. I can see that this code was working fairly recently for other students. Any suggestions on what is going on?

Below is the tutorial's source code:

//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Lottery{

```
// declaring the state variables
address payable[] public players; //dynamic array of type address payable
address public manager; 


// declaring the constructor
constructor(){
    // initializing the owner to the address that deploys the contract
    manager = msg.sender; 
}

// declaring the receive() function that is necessary to receive ETH
receive () payable external{
    // each player sends exactly 0.1 ETH 
    require(msg.value == 0.1 ether);
    // appending the player to the players array
    players.push(payable(msg.sender));
}

// returning the contract's balance in wei
function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
    // only the manager is allowed to call it
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    return address(this).balance;
}

// helper function that returns a big random integer
function random() internal view returns(uint){
   return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players.length)));
}


// selecting the winner
function pickWinner() public{
    // only the manager can pick a winner if there are at least 3 players in the lottery
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    require (players.length >= 3);
    
    uint r = random();
    address payable winner;
    
    // computing a random index of the array
    uint index = r % players.length;

    winner = players[index]; // this is the winner
    
    // transferring the entire contract's balance to the winner
    winner.transfer(getBalance());
    
    // resetting the lottery for the next round
    players = new address payable[](0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copied and pasted the very same code you provided on remix and the contract instance was deployed. You may try to reload your browser like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712347/getting-error-creation-of-helloworld-errored-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefin)